# How to run gulp task with parameter from gulp watch?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I have gulp watch set like this:

```
gulp.watch(somepath, {interval: 500}, ['buildScripts']);
```

And the build scripts looks like this:

```
gulp.task('buildScripts', function (path) {
   //compiles the file from watch
});
```

How can I pass the value of changed file/files so that the `buildScripts` can compile those files?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to factor out your `buildScripts` code into its own function and call that function from both your watch and task. If you don't need the task you can just drop it, of course.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

function buildScripts(changedFile) {
  if (changedFile) {
    // called from watch
    // compile the changed file
  } else {
    // called from task
    // compile all files
  }
}

gulp.task('buildScripts', function() {
  return buildScripts();
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('*.js', {interval:500}, buildScripts);
});
```